# Export multiple charts with one request

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

On page I have 2 charts. They are build with Highcharts library.

I need to export them all as `PNG` files. So I add button, on click on which I need to have 2 separate png-files.

I have function :

```
myApp.highchart.export.create = function (elementId, filename) {
    var chart = $(elementId).highcharts();
    chart.exportChart({ type: 'image/png', filename: filename, sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth });
}
```

I pass in this function Id of every chart, but in result I always get only last chart... I try to add `timeout` but this doesn't help.

I took a look into Network tab in browser and always see only 1 request to `http://export.highcharts.com/`

Can somebody help me with it?

---

Here is example where export for 2 charts works, but in my case this also doesn't help (in example it is used some plugin `highcharts-export-clientside` but I use simple exporting.js)

---

UPD : I've added `highcharts-export-clientside` plugin, but still use highcharts method `exportChart` (in plugin there are `exportChartLocal`). With this plugin It is possible to export multiple charts, but in `png` I get bad formatter chart, all my styles are broken. So I don't know what influence has this plugin when I don't use any of it methods.

---

Also seems like multiple export works in FF but not in Chrome.

---

Example of simple logic : http://jsfiddle.net/6mn2j5pL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you fix it.

> You can use Highcharts.charts for getting array of your charts. Then
>   you can use Highcharts.each for looping over your charts and exporting
>   them one after other.

http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/how-to-export-multiple-charts-to-separate-image-files-t35191/

Solution provided in this forum seems to be working on chrome as well.

Comment: yes, I've tried it... but I have pie-chart with some text inside, and this approach destroy style of that text... so don't know why it is like that (text is styled to be in middle of pie-circle-chart, after export I get this text at the top which overlaps chart series)

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: Have found like temp solution : I can export chart by passing some dynamic iframe-target or just "_blank". This works in every browser (IE 11, Chrome, Mozilla and Safari)